# IE does not show border-bottom for abbr tag

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, abbr

I was surprised to see no search results in Google for this issue :). If you open this w3schools link (https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_abbr_test), you can see that IE does not show any line under the abbr word 'WHO', where as other browsers do. I do not want to add an explicit border-bottom: 1px dotted #color because when the text in other cells of table wraps to multiple lines, the border-bottom added by the application will be pushed far down instead of staying directly underneath the abbr tagged word. I would like to know why IE does not show the line under abbr tags. Thanks for your time!

Here is the codepen for second issue (issue with margin-bottom: auto in IE). If you shrink the size to below 750px, you can see how the line under the abbr tag moves away. If you un-comment the style under abbr[title] I added and try again, the issue gets fixed in other browsers except IE. https://codepen.io/Sankaryc/pen/aGOqoZ

HTML:

```
<div>
  <div class="flex-row">
    <div class="flex-basis-9">
      <label>Field1</label>
  </div>
  <div class="flex-basis-24">Value1 </div>

  <div class="flex-basis-9">
      <label>Field2</label>
  </div>
  <a href="/some-url">dummy url</a>
  <abbr title="StackOverflow" tooltipPosition="bottom">SO</abbr>
    <div class="flex-basis-9"></div>
  <div class="flex-basis-9">
      <label>Field3</label>
  </div>
  <div class="flex-basis-24">Value3 </div>

</div>
```

CSS:

```
div {
  padding-right:2px;
}

.flex-row {
  display:flex;
  line-height:1;
  width:100%;
  margin-top:3px;
}

.flex-basis-9 {
  flex-basis:9%;
}

label {
  padding: 0;
}

.flex-basis-24 {
  flex-basis:24.33%;
}

abbr[title] {
    cursor: help;
    border-bottom: 1.5px dotted #000 !important;
    text-decoration: none !important;
    /*margin-bottom:auto */
}
a {
  padding-right: 10px;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default value for an acronyms and abbreviations in Internet Explorer is `text-decoration: none;`. You can specify the desired style (cross browser) by adding this style definition to your css:

```
abbr[title], acronym[title] {
  text-decoration: none;
  border-bottom: 1px solid dotted;
}
```

**Edit** Your particular problem (as you updated your answer) is not the abbreviation itself, but the flexbox grid you are building. You just need to wrap the `abbr` in a container (a div for example as i did in my case), so the `abbr` itself won't be treated as a flex element by inheritance (as its container has `display: flex;`.

```css
div {
  padding-right:2px;
}

.flex-row {
  display:flex;
  line-height:1;
  width:100%;
  margin-top:3px;
}

.flex-basis-9 {
  flex-basis:9%;
}

label {
  padding: 0;
}

.flex-basis-24 {
  flex-basis:24.33%;
}

abbr[title] {
  position: relative;
  cursor: help;
  text-decoration: none !important;
}
abbr[title]:before {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 1em;
  width: 100%;
  content: '';
  border-bottom: 1px dotted #000 !important;
}
a {
  padding-right: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div class="flex-row">
    <div class="flex-basis-9">
      <label>Field1</label>
  </div>
  <div class="flex-basis-24">Value1 </div>
    
  <div class="flex-basis-9">
      <label>Field2</label>
  </div>
  <a href="/some-url">dummy url</a>
    <abbr title="StackOverflow" tooltipPosition="bottom">SO</abbr>
    <div class="flex-basis-9"></div>
  <div class="flex-basis-9">
      <label>Field3</label>
  </div>
  <div class="flex-basis-24">Value3 </div>
    
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I know that we can border-bottom but my question was why IE does not show the line under abbr tags by default? Chrome and Firefox shows the dotted line by default under abbr tagged word. Is there any other tag we need to use in place of abbr for IE to show the dotted line by default or any other settings to be turned on for IE?

Comment: The answer is simple: IE does not have a default value for that. All other browsers have `text-decoration: dotted underline;`. The default value for IE is `text-decoration: none;`. IE does not support `dotted underline` as a value for `text-decoration` so the best solution will be to override the default value for all browser and use `border-bottom`, that way you don't have to create a specific rule for IE.

Comment: Another issue using border bottom?

Comment: Ok, but what is the isseu with that? It works fine in Internet Explorer.

Comment: That make sense. That is what I am trying to do and running into another IE issue. styles - "abbr[title] {border-bottom: 1px dotted #000 ;  text-decoration: none;   margin-bottom: auto; }". I briefly mentioned this in my question about other cells wrapping due to limited screen size in a table. So, when that happens this bottom-border will not be exactly under the abbr tag (the line goes down as below as 50px from the abbr tag). The solution is adding margin-bottom: auto which works fine in other browsers except IE. Now, I am trying to dig into this IE specific issue with margin-bottom: auto

Comment: I can't reproduce the behavior, can you add the code to your initial post?

Comment: I have created the scenario for you. Please check my question.

Comment: Good to know that it should be inside a div. But, I have this abbr tag in several places and I don't think I have access to physically change the html to add the div tag. Can it be done using CSS? Like, if there is an abbr tag in a grid or grids on the page, wrap it inside div tag without disturbing the layout of the grid? Thanks for your time!

Comment: Yes, why not. I updated my answer to achieve that. (i need to fix it, sorry)

Comment: Done, you can check it now.

Comment: I will verify that and let you know. Thanks for your help!

Comment: I already checked in IE 11, Edge, Chrome (Mac/PC), Firefox (Mac/PC) and Safari.

Comment: I ended up using span tag instead of abbr and that way 1. we can avoid browser added line(which IE does not add anyway) and 2. The line does not go far down when table cells wrap. I appreciate your time @muecas and glad that the discussion went in the right way. Thanks again!

Comment: Great! I'm glad i could help you.